# PostgreSQL to MSSQL Array

Tags: postgresql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write the MSSQL equivalent of this query:

```
(CASE WHEN (to_number((column1), '9') = ANY (ARRAY[(1)::numeric, (5)::numeric])) THEN 'Discontinued' WHEN (to_number((column1), '9') = ANY (ARRAY[(0)::numeric, (3)::numeric, (7)::numeric])) THEN 'Covered' ELSE 'Not Covered' END AS coverage_status,)
```

Answer (score 3):

The array usage in Postgres was overly complex to begin with (not to say useless). This should work:

```
CASE 
   WHEN cast(column1 as integer) in (1,5) THEN 'Discontinued' 
   WHEN cast(column1 as integer) in (0,3,7) THEN 'Covered' 
   ELSE 'Not Covered' 
END AS coverage_status
```

Comment: so can you explain how this works?  to_number((column1)::text, '9'::text and the column text is 63739029910 so the answer is 1.  9 results in a value with the same number of digits as there are 9s. If a digit is not available it outputs a space.  There are 3 nines.